# Can't get pip install to work behind a proxy

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to use pip install behind a proxy server at work to install `beautifulsoup4`. But for some reason I get this output:

```
no such option: -\u2013
```

I'm using python 3.5 and the following command:

```
python -m pip install --proxy http://user:password@proxyserver:port beautifulsoup4
```

Any ideas on what I can do to resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

`\u2013` is –, the en dash, which can easily be confused for a hyphen.  It appears that (likely due to copy & paste issues) one of the hyphens in your command (I suspect the one just before "proxy") is actually an en dash and needs to be replaced with a real hyphen.

Comment: Thank you so much! this helped out a great deal ^-^